# Set<ENUM> to String with separators in Thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I have class filed is called "roles" that have type Set.

```
@Data
@Table(name = "usr")
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
public class User implements UserDetails{
    //...

    @ElementCollection(targetClass = Role.class, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @CollectionTable(name = "user_role", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"))
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Set<Role> roles;

    //...
```

I need to concatenate all elements of the field into one string is separated by a comma in th:text attribute in Thymeleaf. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `#strings.setJoin(set, separator)`:

```
<div th:text="${#strings.setJoin(user.roles, ',')}"></div>
```

See https://doanduyhai.wordpress.com/2012/04/14/spring-mvc-part-iv-thymeleaf-advanced-usage/ for some more info (chapter "Helper objects awesomeness")